# Private subnet not talking to public - health check failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to achieve the following architecture depicted in this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/)

[image]

I have a Fargate Service using an ENI (*with private IP of 10.0.241.85*) running in a *private* subnet (*let's call '**subnet-1**'*). The ENI also has an Elastic IP as it fails to pull the image from ECR if not. I don't think this will matter though? The container in my service is exposing ports 3000/4000. I then have my ALB & NAT gateway in a *public* subnet (*let's call this '**subnet-2**'*). The ALB forwards traffic on ports 80/443 to the necessary target group. The target group has **2** registered tasks targeting the private IP on the ENI (*1 on port 3000 & the other on 4000*). To the best of my knowledge, this should allow traffic in, correct?

For traffic out, ***subnet-1*** has a default route (*0.0.0.0/0*) to the NAT gateway in ***subnet-2***, this should allow traffic out, correct?

All services are in the **same** VPC & the **same** availability zone (*where applicable*)

I have **2** security groups utilised by these services:

1. *test*
2. *api*

***test (inbound)***
[image]

***test (outbound)***
[image]

***api (inbound)***
[image]

***api (outbound)***
[image]

We leverage ephemeral ports for communication between the 2 security groups

***NOTE:*** I removed the destination here but, yeah, the destination is **test** security group

```
| Service | Security Groups |
|---------|-----------------|
| ENI     | test            |
|         | api             |
|---------|-----------------|
| ALB     | api             |
|---------|-----------------|
```

***subnet-1 route table***
[image]

***subnet-2 route table***
[image]

***NOTE:*** The covered route is just a peering connection out so nothing to do with this

From what I know, the 2 subnets should be able to communicate using the private IPs of the services within them which is what I have done here.

The health check fails with the generic message of:

> Task failed ELB health checks

I have also looked to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) blog for a bit more help but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your task is listening on ports 3000 & 4000, your security group (`test` I guess, based on your comments) will need to permit these ports. As configured now, I don't see ports 3000 and 4000 as allowed.

Couple of other notes - an elastic IP on your ENI in a private subnet won't do anything as private subnets cannot have direct access to the internet. If you're having problems connecting to ECR without it there must be some other problem.

Also, your SG rules are permitting very large CIDR blocks like `0.0.0.0/0`. A more secure configuration would only permit the particular security group that needs access. In this case, you would want the ports for your app (sounds like 3000 and 4000) from the SG ID of your load balancer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was not the full answer but was certainly half of it. The other half was that our application throws back a status code of 301 if redirected to HTTPS. The health check was being done over HTTP & was therefore redirected & 301 was not in my Success Code range in my health check